# Word 2013 Textbox Margins

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

I'm creating a document and i'm using textboxes to create columns in it. However, the picture i'm inserting is always getting cut off and is unable to stretch to the max of the textbox width

[image: Example of picture]

[image: Example of picture getting cut off]

Appreciate if someone could help me here!

Comment: Have you checked the textbox's internal margins?